# Excel how to copy 2 rows every nth interval instead of 1 row every nth interval

Tags: excel

I want to copy 2 rows of data and then skip to the next interval and copy the next 2 rows of data. I tried to use =OFFSET(A1,(ROW()-1)*2),0) but this formula will only copy 1 row of data every 2th row. but I want it to copy 2 rows of data every 12th interval.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXrFN.jpg
I only know how to copy 2 rows -> skip 2 rows -> copy 2 rows...

**How do i make it so that it copies 2 rows -> skip 12 rows -> copy 2 rows -> skip 12 rows...etc.?**

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a math problem IMO... but I guess you could use this:

```
=OFFSET(A1,INT((ROW()-1)/2)*4+MOD(ROW()-1,2)+1,0)
```